# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a 'Partial Index'?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

PostgreSQL allows the creation of 'Partial Indexes' which are basically indexes with conditional predicates. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/indexes-partial.html

While testing, I found that they are performing very well for a case where the query is accessing only certain 12 rows in a table with 120k rows.

But before we deploy this, are there any disadvantages or caveats we should be aware of?

Answer (score 6):

The main caveat is not to use them inappropriately.  They are good for identifying rows that match one set of criteria where those rows are the minority in a large table.

Take a table `Orders` for example with an `order_status` column and distribution of your data over the order statuses as follows:

- New 5%
- Backordered 2%
- In Transit 5%
- Completed 85%
- Returned 3%

If you very often query `where order_status = 'New'` to get a list of new orders and then most the rest of the time just reference orders directly by ID, then a partial index would be beneficial.   In your example of 12 rows out of 120k this is even more true.

Comment: +1. Sometimes in production environment indices are added as part of performance tuning. Partial index allows the DBA to tune for specific corner case such as (order_status = 'New') without taking full hit of normal index.

Answer (score 5):

Pro:

> This reduces the size of the index,
>   which will speed up queries that do
>   use the index. It will also speed up
>   many table update operations because
>   the index does not need to be updated
>   in all cases

Con:

Since this no longer is a real index, if you do full join or filtering on values not covered by the index, the performance will degrade as your table size grows.